# disable/enable soft keyboard for webview

Tags: android, webview, keyboard

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.endWith("first.html")) {
        webview.setFocusable(false);
    } else {
        webview.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

At first page, I can disable soft keyboard, and enable it when I navigate to other pages.

But when I back to the first page, the keyboard can't be disabled.

It's weird.

But if I press home key, then back to my app. the keyboard would be disabled again.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer, works perfectly.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.endWith("first.html")) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        // we have to clear focus that gain at other pages.
        View currentFocus = getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
        if (currentFocus != null) {
            currentFocus.clearFocus();
        }
    } else {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: But when the screen is locked and unlocked again by keeping the input focused, it still opens the keyboard. How did you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
 }


@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   if (url.endWith("first.html")) {
        webview.setFocusable(false);
        hideKeyboard(view);
   } else {
        webview.setFocusable(true);
   }
}
```

If this doesn't work there may be some other view gaining focus. You can use a method like this to work to find the view with focus and force the keyboard to be hidden:

```
protected void hideKeyBoard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```